# Jsoup: String element.attr() doesn't work in if()

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm not experienced in Java, and I have a problem.

Using Jsoup, I have an element called td. If I do:

```
String attr = td.attr("class");
System.out.println(attr);
```

The output is "free", which is perfectly alright. If I do:

```
String attr = td.attr("class");
if (attr == "free") {
System.out.println("freedom!");
}
```

There is no output!

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Yes, you are right. Because I am new to Java, I didn't see this, because I thought it was a problem with Jsoup specifically. Now I see the answer I understand that my thoughts were completely wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to compare the string using the `equals` method as `==` compare references, not strings contents.

```
String attr = td.attr("class");
if (attr.equals("free")) {
    System.out.println("freedom!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! When I see it like this, it's logical, but I'm not experienced in Java.